# Volumes of Revolutions : Lord of the Rings

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

> > Question: The "Lord of the Rings" has a collection of solid gold rings for different-sizes fingers. The cross section of each ring is a segment of a circle radius $R$ as shown in the diagram below. All rings in the collection have the same width $w$.
> >
> > The "Lord of the Rings" says to Gandaulf, "although the rings have different diameters, they all contain the same amount of gold."
> >
> > Is this true?. Justify your answer.
> >
> > Picture: [image]

---

I am stuck setting up the volume of revolution:

I get the circle as $x^2+y^2=R^2$ but I'm trouble locating the limits of the integration and any other things I have to do...

Comment: can you specify more clearly your problem ?

Comment: @Boris This is the all the information I have recieved..

Comment: This is easiest to deal with by using the method of cylindrical shells:  your shell radii will run from  $ \ x \ = \ r \ $  to $ \ x \ = \ R \ $  , though you will ultimately need to use a u-substitution integral.  (I just wrote up a solution for this problem for my class.)  You can put the $ \ x-$ axis through the horizontal plane of symmetry of the ring and the height of the shell is determined from the circle equation.   (You can probably find the "napkin ring" problem solved online as well...)  You will find that the volume can be expressed as a function of $ \ w \ $ alone.

Comment: It's Gandalf, not Gandaulf.

Comment: @hypergeometric Apologies, that is how the question was typed out.

Comment: That's alright. Just saying... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to integrate; the volume of the ring is the difference between two well-known volumes. The [spherical segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_segment) with height $w$ and both radii $r$ has volume $\frac{\pi w}6\left(3r^2+3r^2+w^2\right)$, and the cylinder cut out of it has volume $\pi r^2w$. The difference is

$$
\frac{\pi w}6\left(3r^2+3r^2+w^2\right)-\pi r^2w=\frac{\pi w^3}6\;.
$$

So the Lord of the Rings was right.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not too familiar why the volume is that.. this question was also given under integration so I think we would have to use volumes of revolutions right>

Comment: @dydxx: This is why you're supposed to provide context in the question. If you're only interested in answers using integration, the question should have stated that. I used the formula from the Wikipedia article on spherical segments I linked to. You can obtain it by integration.

Comment: Certainly it is true that the problem can be solved using the mensuration formulas for a sphere, a cylinder and two spherical "caps" (or the one segment).  However, it is likely that a student is going to be asked to prove the spherical cap or segment formulas before applying either (I certainly would require that be done in the submission of a solution).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: The question didn't specify that the OP is a student. It's bad enough that people so often fail to provide context; it's even worse when others are then made responsible for the results.

Comment: @dydxx joriki is using a well discovery by Cavalieri that the volume of a spehre can be described as the volume of a cylinder less the volume of a cone. Always good to think about classical geometry before jumping into the calculus.

Answer (score 1):

If we use the Disc method and symmetry, we get

$\displaystyle V=2\int_0^{w/2}\pi\left((R(y))^2-(r(y))^2\right)dy=2\pi\int_0^{w/2}\left((R^2-y^2)-\big(R^2-\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)^2\big)\right)dy$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.2 in}=2\pi\int_0^{w/2}\left(\frac{w^2}{4}-y^2\right)dy=2\pi\left[\frac{w^2}{4}\big(y\big)-\frac{y^3}{3}\right]_0^{w/2}=\frac{\pi w^3}{6}$

(using that $R(y)=x$ and $r(y)=r$)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the shaded area, which is a circular segment.

Let $2\theta$=angle subtended by the arc of this segment.

Area of segment, $$A=\frac 12 R^2(2\theta-\sin 2\theta)$$

Distance of [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centroids) of circular segment from centre of ring, 
$$s=\frac 43R \left(\frac {\sin^3\theta}{2\theta-\sin 2\theta}\right)$$
By [Pappus' centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem), volume of ring is given by cross-sectional area multiplied by length travelled by centroid, i.e. 
$$\begin{align}
V&=A\cdot 2\pi s\\
&=\frac 43 \pi(R\sin\theta)^3 \\
&=\frac 43\pi \left(\frac w2\right)^3\\
&=\frac \pi 6 w^3\end{align}$$
which is constant, as $w$ is constant.